# Android: download image and put it in the res/drawable folder

Tags: android

Is it possible (and, if yes, how) to download an image from the internet and put it in the res/drawable folder?

I need to do it because I tried to download the images and put them in a folder of the application (with Context.getFilesDir()) but in this way it slow down a lot on the Galaxy S4 (and for "a lot" I mean 20 - 30 times the galaxy S2).

Obviously I don't need to refer those images in the layout xml...

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers... as I thought this is not possible. I've found a workaround for this: I'm using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for Android and it seems to work really smooth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `res` folder is zipped into the APK. I can't think of a way, without root access, of injecting things into it. Further more, I don't think that downloading it into a different directory is actually going to speed things up anyway.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible at runtime. The res/drawable folder is wrapped up inside your APK and there is no way to change it.